# Yahoo Messenger vs Server Push on Web page

Tags: chat

Long before gtalk popularized the concept of server push, Yahoo messenger(desktop client) used to push messages instantly to the users. A person behind a firewall was able to use Yahoo messenger without any issue. So was Yahoo messenger using http ?. And was it using a server push ?

Thanks